# Efficiently counting tokens column-wise in Bash/Awk/Perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have the following output from a pipeline.

```
Lorem dolor sit amet consectetur
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ,
Lorem dolor sit amet ,
Lorem dolor ipsum sit !
```

---

### Edit

The number of columns is specified by me/the user, but unlikely to be more than 10. My biggest data set so far looks like this:

```
prev_command | wc -l
$ 23805483
```

There are north of 300,000 unique tokens if I remember correctly.

---

Fields are separated by a space. Fields may contain all sorts of special symbols (→æ€…ð), but no spaces or tabs. I don't necessarily know the number of columns.

For every column (field), I need sorted word counts: essentially `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`. Desired output:

```
4 Lorem 3 dolor 2 sit   2 amet 2 ,
        1 ipsum 1 dolor 2 sit  1 consectetur
                1 ipsum        1 !
```

Ideally, value and key are delimited by a space, and each val-key pair by a tab. Since the lenghts are different, line 3 would actually be `\s\t\s\t1\sipsum\t\s\t1\s!`.

What I have so far is a shell script that kinda works, but there are several things I don't like about it. Here are the relevant lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
trap 'rm -rf -- "$tmp"' EXIT

data="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
[ "$data" != "$1" ] && cat $data > $tmp/table && data="$tmp/table"

count() {
    sort | uniq -c | sort -rn \
      | awk -v x=" " '{ print $1 x $2 }'
}

# infer column number from first line
ncol=$(head -1 $data | wc -w)

# loop over columns in parallel and save each in temporary file
for i in $(seq $ncol); do
  cut -f $i -d " " $data | count > $tmp/col$i &
done
wait

paste $tmp/col[0-9]*
```

1. How can I directly take a data stream on stdin and still have the option to take a file argument without losing much speed? If I remove the step with the tempfile, and pipe the original pipeline into the script, I still get an output, but not the expected one. Not sure what's going on. I experimented with `while read -ra...`, but didn't know what to do inside the loop.
2. Any way I can avoid the whole tempfile business? In some cases, the input may be too large to hold in memory. It's also kind of painful to get the output into the right format with paste since it is ragged. When I want tabs only, I currently pipe it into a `sed -e 's/\t\t/\t\t\t/g' -e 's/^\t/\t\t/g'`. Bleargh. Same with `uniq -c` which has leading whitespace.
3. How can I speed this up? I do have a perl version of `count()`, but it's essentially doing the same thing and not taking care of i/o.

I'd prefer a bash/awk solution over perl since I don't know much perl and would prefer a solution that I understand (and also minimize dependencies). But if someone knows a mind-boggingly fast perl approach, I'd gladly take it. :D

This task seems pretty straightforward to me, but I couldn't find anything that handles variable columns and piped input.
Thanks in advance for any tips! :)

Comment: Can you estimate how many columns (C) and lines (L) you have on average? An efficient solution for C << L may be very inefficient for C >> L and vice versa. Also, the size of the file would be helpful. If it is small enough to be held in memory, then that might simplify things a lot.

Comment: Not that it answers the question, but I prefer a not-bash solution for moderately-complex questions. (I use Python because I'm more familiar with it, but perl is usually okay too with proper conventions)

Comment: The number of columns is specified manually at some point prior to this and generally around 3-10.

I cannot easily install anything over where I run this or for the users of the finished utility. So I was trying to push it as far as I could in shell.

Comment: Done. I did mentioned that it was too big to hold in memory, but I could have made it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

another `awk` solution

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) c[i,$i]++;next} 
               {f=line=""; 
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                  {k=i SUBSEP $i; 
                   if(k in c) 
                     {f=1; line=line sprintf("%d %s",c[k],$i); delete c[k]}; 
                   line=line "\t"} 
                   if(f) print line}' file{,}


4 Lorem 3 dolor 2 sit   2 amet  1 consectetur
        1 ipsum 1 dolor 2 sit   2 ,
                1 ipsum         1 !
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton to show the same script pretty-printed by `gawk -o-`:

```
NR == FNR {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        c[i, $i]++
    }
    next
}

{
    f = line = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        k = i SUBSEP $i
        if (k in c) {
            f = 1
            line = line sprintf("%d %s", c[k], $i)
            delete c[k]
        }
        line = line "\t"
    }
    if (f) {
        print line
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I edited your answer to show the same script using a little different format for line wraps, indentation etc. as output by `gawk -o-` because I always admire your coding skill but I always **really** struggle to follow the scripts you post due to the formatting you use and have to run them through `gawk -o-` before I can understand them. So, this is just a suggestion/request to maybe try adopting a more common formatting style for C-like languages that IMHO is far easier to read? Feel free to just delete my edit.

Comment: Thank you, learned a lot from you. No problem if this format is more readable.  I like my code little more dense due to perhaps my vision problems.

Comment: Took me a while to understand because I assumed each column in the output would be sorted by the word count. However, the output of this script may be unsorted (as can be seen in the last column here).

Comment: Right, I missed that. It follows the text order, so it's not sorted by the count.

Comment: @karakfa Thank you for the suggestion. Could you explain what the `{,}` after `file` does (tricky to search for :D)? I can't seem to get it to work with stdin. Also: is there a quick fix on the sorting issue? I've got as far as adding `BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" }`.

Comment: bash expands `file{,}` to `file file`, easier to write the filename twice.  This script is double scanning the file and counts in the first round prints the words in the second round in place, so for sorting and reading from stdin you need a different approach and do the printing in the `END` block.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. However, it, unfortunately, neither improves speed nor does it solve my problem reading from stdin without a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a pure Perl implementation that has one dependency for rendering the output. I've tested it against [the complete works of William Shakespeare from Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt), which is a 5.5MB text file. <strike>On my machine that took about 34s and consumed a max of 180MB of memory.</strike><sup>1</sup>

On my machine, this took roughly 5 seconds.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Text::Table::Tiny 'generate_table';

# read line by line, split into words on whitespace, count per column
my @counts;
while (<>) {
    my $i;
    $counts[$i++]->{$_}++ for split;
}

# sort columns into a new datastructure
my ( $row_count, @sorted_cols ) = (0);
for (my $col = 0; $col <= $#counts; $col++) {
        push @{ $sorted_cols[$col] },
            map [ $counts[$col]->{$_}, $_ ],
            sort {
                # this sorts on count first, and ascii-betical second
                $counts[$col]->{$b} <=> $counts[$col]->{$a} || $a cmp $b
            } keys %{ $counts[$col] };
        $row_count = $#{ $sorted_cols[$col] }
            if $#{ $sorted_cols[$col] } > $row_count;
}

# output
say generate_table(
    rows => [
        map {
            my $row = $_;
            [
                map $_->[$row] ? @{ $_->[$row] } : (q{}, q{}), @sorted_cols
            ];
        } 0 .. $row_count
    ],
    style       => 'norule'
);
```

The data is read line by line. Perl's `<>` operator will either read from STDIN or open and real all filenames passed in as command line arguments.

The first pass over the data counts occurrences of each word per column, builds up a data structure with these and discards the actual text. It takes advantage of the bare form of `split`, which makes it behave like awk, stripping off any whitespace.

The second block of code will iterate the counts and sort them, producing a new data structure that holds two columns (count and word) per input column. Sorting is done on count descending, and on word ascending. We also figure out how many rows of output we need to generate, because that depends on the longest column here.

Lastly, we use [Text::Table::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table::Tiny) to generate the output. You can get that from CPAN or your distribution repository.

---

<sup>1) See revision history for previous version</sup>

Comment: Upon having run this through Devel::NYTProf, I am wondering if Text::Table was the best choice. Text::Table uses Text::Aligner, which took nearly 100x the run time of my code. About 10% of that time is Term::ANSIColor for stripping out (non-existent, in our case) colour escape sequences.

Comment: I've changed it to Text::Table::Tiny, which makes it run in 4.6s rather than 35s. Will update my answer, and then run NYTProf again to see about memoization.

Comment: I'm limited to what's preinstalled wherever I'm running this, and I'm running out of memory with your script for my bigger datasets. I did a tiny bit of testing without the table bit, and it took longer than by version. Still helps because it gives me something to dissect for related tasks, thanks!

Comment: @alex Sorry about the memory. Must be a hell of a lot of data. How big is big? In terms of shipping it, if your dependencies are pure Perl, you can [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-FatPacker/bin/fatpack) them all into your code and ship them in one big file. Your users will never even realise it.

Comment: I edited my biggest dataset at the top. Thanks for the tip concerning fatpack! I'll definitely play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. If I remove the step with the tempfile, and pipe the original pipeline into the script, I still get an output, but not the expected one. Not sure what's going on.

stdin can only be read once. When you read something then it is gone. This is a problem for `for i in {1..3}; do cut -f $i; done`. In the first iteration `cut` reads the whole file but discards most of its columns except the first one. Nevertheless, the other columns were read and are therefore gone. In the next iteration the file is empty and `cut -f2` and `cut -f3` won't print anything. Since you executed all `cut`s in parallel using `&` all of them will read a bit of the input but none will read everything.

> 2. Any way I can avoid the whole tempfile business? In some cases, the input may be too large to hold in memory.

You can use variables instead of temporary files as long as you have enough memory. With the following approach you don't need to hold the whole input in memory, but only the result. I guess that shouldn't be a problem.

#### Skeleton of an AWK Solution

```
awk '{
  for (col = 1; col <= NF; ++col) {
    ++count[col " " $col]
  }
} END {
  for (colWord in count) {
   split(colWord, s, " ")
   col=s[1]
   word=s[2]
   print col " " count[colWord] " " word
  }
}' "$@" | sort -k1,1n -k2,2nr
```

This prints

```
1 4 Lorem
2 3 dolor
2 1 ipsum
3 2 sit
3 1 dolor
3 1 ipsum
4 2 amet
4 2 sit
5 2 ,
5 1 !
5 1 consectetur
```

But transforming this into the final output is hell. I'd advise to use any language that supports *real* multidimensional arrays and sorting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation of what is going wrong in my loop.

Ha! This output actually helps me for a different output option I wanted to add. It runs significantly slower than my version though, and I do run out of memory with my biggest dataset, which is a bit of a bummer. But it helped a lot nevertheless. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. You can circumvent the memory problems by splitting the biggest dataset into smaller chunks and aggregating the intermediate results after sorting. For aggregating in this format  you only have to store two lines of the result format at a time.

Comment: Thinking about that a bit more, I guess it would be faster to do *only* the aggregation part. Decorate each field with its column number, then `sort | uniq -c` that: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) print i " " $i}' | sort | uniq -c`. Afterwards you can sort by count and column again, using `sort -k ...`.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's generate a more interesting example. This is easy in Python:

```
from pathlib import Path 
import string 
import random 

p='/tmp/bigfile.txt'

target=string.digits+string.ascii_letters+'!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~.'
tgt=300_000
toks=set()

while len(toks)<tgt:
    toks.add(''.join(random.choices(target, k=random.randrange(1,15))))
    
toks=list(toks) 

tgt=100_000_000
out={0:[]}
while sum(len(e) for e in out.values())<tgt:
    for key in range(1,11):
        out.setdefault(key, []).append(random.choice(toks))
    out[0].append('foo')
    
with open(p, 'w') as f: 
    for j in range(len(out[0])):
        f.write('\t'.join([out[i][j] for i in range(11)])+'\n')
```

Since there will be 300,000 unique tokens between 1 and 15 characters long and 100,000,000 total, the average count should be near 300 for each token or roughly 30 for each token in each column.

Now run `wc` on the resulting file:

```
$ wc bigfile.txt
 9090910 100000010 885069908 bigfile.txt
```

The file is 9,090,910 lines, 100,000,010 words and 885,069,908 bytes.

Now you can count uniques with this `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) cnt[$i]++} END{for (e in cnt) print cnt[e], e}' bigfile.txt | sort -n | tail -n 2
388 e!,#?
9090910 foo
```

You can also run the same `awk` though `head` to see the least frequent.
Column 0 has nothing but `foo` in it and acts as a line count later...

Here is a Ruby to process this file. It uses sparse matrices to hold the counts of tokens and also lines up the digits and tokens of the output into a table.

This will also handle input that has a variable number of columns.

Ruby is a lovely language, but not known for speed. This is likely fairly memory efficient, however, and is processing the file in one pass.

```
ruby -lane '
BEGIN{ h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) } 
        w=Hash.new(0); cols=0; max_cnt=Hash.new(0) }

cols=$F.length()>cols ? $F.length() : cols
$F.each_with_index {|f, i| 
        h[i][f]+=1 
        max_cnt[i]=h[i][f]>max_cnt[i] ? h[i][f] : max_cnt[i]
        w[i]=f.length()>w[i] ? f.length : w[i]
} 

END{ 
    max_cnt.each { |k,v| max_cnt[k]=Math::log10(v).to_i+2 }
    rows=h.max_by{ |k, sl| sl.length() }[1].length()
    h.each {|k,v| h[k]=h[k].sort_by {|k,v| -v }
        .map{|tok,cnt| sprintf("%*d %-*s ",max_cnt[k], cnt, w[k], tok) }
    }
    (0..rows).each {|i| s=""
        (0..cols-1).each {|j| 
            x=h[j][i]==nil ? " "*h[j][0].length : h[j][i] 
            s+=x 
        }
        puts s
    }
}' bigfile.txt >bigproc.txt
```

With the generated file, the `head` and `tail` are:

```
$ head -n 2 bigproc.txt
 9090910 foo  60 8[K(`=@irD69    59 )*2`t/o         59 =Ez!O           60 V5`;z           61 &_iX]#1         58 ai@Ita+mMl.D    57 W9)6,LB         59 f^>kE#]/]2I.F   58 YH@?nR@xVI.v].  61 <A8            
              60 O5w&]V0I//JQ0   58 ?>HSLYM+        58 ExB`xSt[,Gk     57 SE{e            60 `Aeeb~Wp<+&4R[  56 .aP             57 QoN.W)          58 JoZ<KQrE        57 Xk9             58 (A.O
```

And:

```
$ tail -n 3 bigproc.txt 
              10 N;rZ            10 #kTm            10 yA^&^            9 e<5}=Q8;e.      10 7Hy$             9 OZ36k61<xKo     11 -^@)0y}wQ(s      8 f8ECm.dK9       10 v4u              9 Cxu|/f69$e     
               9 +?r|T;           9 ]qLWb[aM=        9 Jul@xGw          9 =]#zPhy9$w/s!    9 $/YZc7&D|        8 EgA])%(         10 !XYWwuM0y2oO     7 }ty&J[G.Ld^w     8 PPMB@WbL<>E0S    9 spLPi.x)e9
```

The example file is processed in 1:36 and uses 667 MB peak memory.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't test it as it throughs an error:
```
-e:20:in `rescue in block (4 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ```
Maybe I am missing a dependency or the server I'm working on has the wrong version.

Comment: @alexraw: I rewrote the section that might produce a `rescue` block. Could you try again?

Comment: Thanks, it executes just fine now, but only returns 4 lines and a looot of tabs/whitespace between the columns. My actual data set is much longer than in the example, see above.

Comment: I fixed the 4 lines just now; try again?

Comment: Pretty much the same. Only got a tiny bit more output.

Comment: Maybe try this last one *one more time* I fixed two bugs that were causing the printout of less than total. I added a test file that shows that it is working.

Comment: Output looks fine, looks like the safest on memory and the quickest among the suggestions so far. :) I still get an error though:
```
-e:23:in `write': Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)
```
Still not nearly as fast as my original solution with temporary files and GNU utilities.